# Good encoding for VARCHAR with similarity across rows

Tags: encoding, amazon-redshift

What is a good Amazon Redshift column encoding for a VARCHAR column where each row contains a short (usually 50-100 characters) value that contains little repetition, but for which there is a high degree of similarity across the rows? (Identical prefixes, in particular.)

The maddeningly terse [LZO description](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/lzo-encoding.html) makes it sound like LZO is applied individually to each value. In that case, there will be no shared dictionary across the rows and little commonality to exploit. OTOH, if the LZO is applied to an entire 1 MB block of values written to disk, it would perform well.

[Byte Dictionary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Byte_dictionary_encoding.html) sounds like it only yields savings when the values are identical rather than similar, so not a good option.

Comment: The Amazon Redshift `ANALYZE COMPRESSION` command automatically recommends a compression setting for each column, based upon the first 100,000 rows. What is it suggesting for this particular data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression is applied per block, which means that `LZO` is almost always the right choice for `VARCHAR`. Most of the other alternatives require the values to be either completely identical to other values (e.g. `BYTEDICT`, `RUNLENGTH`), or be numeric (e.g. `DELTA`, `MOSTLY8`).

The only other alternative for `VARCHARS` is [`TEXT255`/`TEXT32K`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Text255_encoding.html), which might work for your use case. They build dictionaries of the first N words (245 for `TEXT255` and variable for `TEXT32K`) and replaces occurrences of these words with a one byte index. If your values share a lot of words then `TEXT255` might work better than `LZO`.